# How to tell whether NSURLConnection has cached a certain image?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

How would I go about finding out whether a UIImage has already been cached with NSURLConnection?

example:

```
if([NSURLCache containsObject:[UIImage imageNamed@"testPic.png"]]){
NSLog(@"item already cached!");
}
```

obviously the above code doesn't work but you get the point...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a copy of your request, then later ask the sharedCache:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

The returned object has a bunch of stuff in it including the data object.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more or give me an example?

Comment: Its just as I said. When you do a NSURLConnection, save the NSURLRequest in an ivar. Then later you can ask the NSURLCache for a cached response. If you get an object back, then ask it for its data (if that is what you want) "NSData *data = [cachedResponse data];" The class description for NSCachedURLResponse has other properties you can request too.